# Are Excel linked paths relative or absolute?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

Let's say I have a group of XLS files in a folder, and I want to link the tabular data in them to a new XLSX so I can graph it.

If I move the entire folder to a different path, computer or storage device, can I expect the links to still work?  Are there any special settings or techniques I should be aware of to make this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both. Excel deliberately stores both the relative and the absolute path of linked items in order to try and find the linked items when the file is opened.

When you open a file, Excel will first try the *relative* path to find the file. If this fails, it will then try the *absolute* path to the file. If this succeeds, Excel will update the relative path on the document when you next save.

If Excel cannot find the file either via the relative *or* the absolute file path, then the item becomes unlinked.

Comment: Thanks.  I also found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328440